# Working example of EF plus audit features in github

Tags: asp.net, audit, audit-logging, entity-framework-plus

I am trying to use EF plus audit features in ASP .NET project. Is there any working example in github which i can  download & run in VisualStudio ( after doing necessary changes related to DB) ?
All the examples I see is with FiddleHelper which does not have the complete code and hence does not run in VS. Please share a working example in github.

Thanks,
Nilanjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample from the link you have given.
Step 1: Download the code into your local box.
Step 2: Update the connection string inside appsettings.json
Step 3: Please create 3 tables inside your database. Please refer to the "**Scripts**" folder.
Step 4: Execute the console application and see the data getting populated.
Please let me know if you need any assistance.

GitHub URL: https://github.com/vishipayyallore/mini-projects-2021/tree/master/Projects/EFPlusAuditDemo

**appsettings.json file for reference**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SqlServerConnection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\LocalDbSessions;Initial Catalog=BooksStoreData;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
  }
}
```

[image: Tables getting populated]

[image: Create Tables using these scripts]

Comment: This does not have the complete code to run in Visual Studio. I am looking for the Solution project which i can download from github and import in Visual Studio

Comment: Are you looking at some specific item? OR Any sample which shows the basics of the concept?

Comment: I am looking for the complete working code for this example https://dotnetfiddle.net/ETFLlO

Comment: Got it. Please give me a couple of hours and I will check the code into my GitHub Repository. I hope a console application should be enough.

Comment: Did a sample from the link you have given and checked into GitHub Repository. Please review.

Comment: Thanks Viswanatha !..i didn't get the Github link for your code...Can you please share it with me

Comment: @NilanjanRoy, Added the GitHub Link. You can read the Audit table and use it according to your use case.

Comment: Can you please share the github link for the source code of the console app you created

Comment: https://github.com/vishipayyallore/mini-projects-2021/tree/master/Projects/EFPlusAuditDemo

Comment: @NilanjanRoy, Actually I have added the URL in the main Answer. Please view the Original answer too. Please let me know if you need any assistance.

Comment: I think still I am missing the link. i believe this is your github location  https://github.com/vishipayyallore?tab=repositories&q=&type=&language=&sort= ...whats the project name

Comment: <<https://github.com/vishipayyallore/mini-projects-2021/tree/master/Projects/EFPlusAuditDemo>>

Comment: Did you get it now

Comment: Thanks ..I got it ...let me try it

Comment: Hi Viswanatha, 
In your code "Retrieve AuditEntries for specific item" portion is commented out.Can you please give it a try like how it is fetching all the records for a specific Customer 
Thanks

Comment: Sure. Is it OK if I give you by Monday? Please advise.